# How does "auth code and access/refresh token" exchange happens in Google oAuth flow

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth

Sorry, for what I am asking might be obvious. I've been thinking, is this the Client Library (for php, python, etc) that generates the access token itself based on the Auth code we receive after a user fulfills the consent screen OR the client library requests the Google server for the access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in step 5 of [the flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp), it's an HTTPS call to Google.

> To exchange an authorization code for an access token, call the https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token endpoint